# how load page with different content from multiple query from multiple table on scroll?

Tags: php, ajax, database

I'm trying to lode page on scroll but the data which i want show is from different-different query's and save in different-different variables and show on page by using separate 's data is dynamic so it can be 10 element or 100 in each  and there is no relation between one  data to another.

i have tried loading on scroll using ajax but in that there is a relation in all data of some kind. so they are putting condition on that like only showing 1-10 id_no element and on scroll calling ajax which send data from 11-20 id_no element but i don't have that option.

Comment: By 'I don't have that option' do you mean you cant pass GET or POST parameters?

Comment: Could you please add some code examples to your question? You will be able to get answers quicker if others can understand the exact problem you face.